# trigger at particular column with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to check a Column value when update.If its match insert into another table.
My Tables:[image: FirstTable]

[image: SecondTable]

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test
ON test1
FOR UPDATE
AS
    SET nocount ON

    IF ( Update(sname) )
      DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR

    DECLARE @id INT

    SET @id=@@IDENTITY 
    SET @Name=(SELECT sname
               FROM   test1
               WHERE  id = @id)

    IF( @Name = 'Paras' )
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO test2
                      (loginfo)
          VALUES     ('success')
      END
```

And my update query is:

```
update Test1 set Sname='Paras' where ID=1
```

When I run this update query Nothing is happen.`Test2` table is empty.I think problem is  `@@IDENTITY` but not sure.Thanks.

Comment: @@IDENTITY :Is a system function that returns the last-inserted identity value.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: Oh Its a mistake. so how I find updated column `ID`?

Comment: Also: be aware that a trigger in SQL Server is called **once per statement** (not once per row). It could be called for an `INSERT` statement that inserted 50 rows at once. You need to deal with that fact - don't assume your trigger only deals with a single row!

Comment: @ShreeKhanal marc_s is right, though in other databases(e.g. Postgresql) call your trigger per row, in Sql Server, it's per statement, you have to use `inserted` table and `deleted` table for UPDATE trigger. For INSERT trigger, use `inserted` table; for DELETE trigger, use `deleted` table

Comment: @ShreeKhanal "how I find updated column `ID`?" You get it from `inserted` table. But it's better to use `EXISTS`, as any statement can affect many rows, and the way Sql Server trigger operates is not amenable on row-by-row trigger code treatment, a trigger is called once per statement, not per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test
ON test1
FOR UPDATE
AS
    SET nocount ON

    IF ( Update(sname) )
      DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR

    DECLARE @id INT

    SET @id=(select id from inserted) 
    SET @Name=(SELECT sname
               FROM   inserted
               WHERE  id = @id)

    IF( @Name = 'Paras' )
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO test2
                      (loginfo)
          VALUES     ('success')
      END
```

But it's better to do this, an update can update many rows, the above will fail if UPDATE matches many rows, use EXISTS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test
ON test1
FOR UPDATE
AS
    SET nocount ON

    IF( EXISTS(select * From inserted where sname = 'Paras' ) )
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO test2
                      (loginfo)
          VALUES     ('success')
      END
```

`inserted` table is the name of the table where the UPDATE's new values goes, `deleted` table is the name of the table where UPDATE's old values goes

Comment: Which ID is select.I want to select updated column ID but how i don't know?Any Idea?

Comment: You can get the `ID` from `inserted` table. But you don't need to re-query the `test1` table based on the `ID` you obtained, all the updated & old values for an UPDATE statement are already in `inserted` & `deleted` tables respectively

Comment: Thanks.I got about `inserted`.I test it.But problem is same `Test2` table is still empty.No data is insert in `Test2`.

Comment: Try to `PRINT` debug your code. Put `PRINT @Name`, before `if` statement, check if `@Name` has a value

Comment: I got a typo there, change the `name` to `sname`. should be this: `IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE sname = 'Paras') )`

Comment: Mistake line `DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR`. change it `NVARCHAR(50)` and its work.Thanks a lot.